# Lucas Theorem on a sector

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Let $P(z)$ be a polynomial with non-negative real coefficients. Suppose  $P(z)$  has all its zeros in a sector  $S $ with sector angle greater than $\pi$ contains all the zeros of $P(z).$  My intuition says that $P'(z)$ also has its all zeros in $S.$ Am I correct or wrong? If correct, how can I  proceed with the proof ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $P(z) = z^2 + z + 1$.  Its zeros are in the sector $-2\pi/3 \le \theta \le 2\pi/3$, but the zero of $P'$ is $-1/2$ which is not.

Comment: Can we conclude that  for non-convex sector, Lucas Theorem is not true?

Comment: For any non-convex open set $S$ there is a polynomial with its roots in $S$ whose derivative has a root not in $S$.  Namely, take two points $a,b \in S$ such that $(a+b)/2 \notin S$, and the polynomial is $(z-a)(z-b)$.