# Lucas Theorem on a Sector for a special class of polynomials

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I had asked a question sometime back [Lucas Theorem on a sector](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346591/lucas-theorem-on-a-sector). But it seems that for the below subclass of polynomials it may be true. Here is my claim;
Let $P(z)$ be a polynomial of degree $n,$ with real and non-negative coefficients having all its zeros in an open sector region $S=\{re^{i\theta}|\theta\in(0,\phi), r\geq 0\}$ where $\phi\in[0, 2\pi]$ then $p'(z)$  has all its zeros in $S.$

If the sector angle $\phi$ is less than or equal to $\pi,$ (convex region) we are done as it follows directly from Lucas Theorem. We need to prove it for the case $\phi>\pi$ (non-convex region). Any hint or suggestion?